# CYPHER query based on sum relationship property array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my graph, relationships have a property named `list`. `list` is an array of int.

It looks like this:

```
(head:Node)-[r:RELATIONSHIP {list:...}]->(tail:Node)
```

I'd like to query all tails in the graph, where the sum of list is > 0.

Intuitively, I would do:

```
MATCH (:Node)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(tail:Node)
WHERE sum(r.list) > 0
RETURN tail
```

This does not work unfortunately. It throws an error. How can I write this query?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
MATCH (:Node)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(tail:Node)
WHERE REDUCE(s = 0, v IN r.list | s + v) > 0
RETURN tail
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want

MATCH p=(n1:Node)-[:RELATIONSHIP*2..2]->(n2:Node)
with n1 as head, n2 as tail, REDUCE(totalScore = 0.0, r in relationships(p) | totalScore + toFloat(r.score)) as score
where score>1.99
return head.name, tail.name, score

Notes:
In my example I'm specifying a fixed path length of 2, so that I could check the total scores easily...
If you graph has bidirectional relationships or loops, know that head=tail is possible...